# Converting string/chr to date using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, hive, dplyr, sparklyr

I've brought a table into Hue which has a column of dates and i'm trying to play with it using sparklyr in Rstudio.

I'd like to convert a character column into a date column like so:

```
Weather_data = mutate(Weather_data, date2 = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

and this runs fine but when i check:

```
head(Weather_data)
```

[image]

How to I properly convert the chr to dates?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you provide the data in `dput(Weather_data)` format  _before_ you applied the conversion?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry, i'm not the best with R or using hue so I'm not quite sure what you mean. But when I brought the data into hue, I tried to select the column type as date but when it showed the output, it was all NAs so I used string instead

Comment: `sdf_mutate(Weather_data, date2 = as.Date(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))`

Comment: Thank you for your message. THis gave me the error:

Comment: Error in as.Date.default(list(src = list(con = list(master = "yarn-client",  : 
  c("do not know how to convert 'structure(list(src = structure(list(con = structure(list(master = \"yarn-client\", ' to class “Date”", "do not know how to convert '    method = \"shell\", app_name = \"sparklyr\", config.......

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that `sparklyr` doesn't correctly support Spark `DateType`. It is possible to parse dates, and correct format, but not represent these as proper `DateType` columns. If that's enough then please follow the instructions below.

In Spark 2.2 or later use `to_date` with Java `SimpleDataFormat` compatible string:

```
df <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(date=c("01/01/2010")))
parsed <- df %>% mutate(date_parsed = to_date(date, "MM/dd/yyyy"))
parsed
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
        date date_parsed
       <chr>       <chr>
1 01/15/2010  2010-01-15
```

Interestingly internal Spark object still uses `DateType` columns:

```
parsed %>% spark_dataframe
```

```
<jobj[120]>
  class org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
  [date: string, date_parsed: date]
```

For earlier versions `unix_timestamp` and `cast` (but watch for possible timezone problems):

```
df %>%
  mutate(date_parsed = sql(
    "CAST(CAST(unix_timestamp(date, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS timestamp) AS date)"))
```

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
        date date_parsed
       <chr>       <chr>
1 01/15/2010  2010-01-15
```

**Edit**:

It looks like this problem has been resolved on current master (`sparklyr_0.7.0-9105`):

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# Database: spark_connection
        date date_parsed
       <chr>      <date>
1 01/01/2010  2009-12-31
```

Comment: beware that the timezone default in the JVM will play dirty tricks here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49355077/how-to-convert-a-timestamp-into-string-without-changing-timezone

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ In practice timezone should be always configured explicitly for the Spark session - otherwise things can get ugly pretty fast (which much more serious outcomes than the one linked, which is actually intended and documented :). So you either need `extraJavaOptions` or respective Spark SQL config.

Comment: great! do you know what would be the correct command with javaextraoptions to set UTC?

Comment: Old way `--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Duser.timezone=UTC"` or if you use `spark-submit` or equivalent in Spark configuration. New way (2.2+) `--conf spark.sql.session.timeZone=UTC`. A few answers (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bapache-spark%5D+spark.sql.session.timeZone) if you want to give a credit to some user :) The possible gotcha is that things get weird, if for some crazy reason different nodes have different settings :)